# ES6 Arrow function with brackets

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I came across a little problem in my code which was kind of confusing to me and hope someone could explain why it does the things it does.

**Code 1**

```
sendText(){
    return this.http.get('/api')
        .map((response:Response) => response.json());
}
```

**Code 2**

```
sendText(){
    return this.http.get('/api').map((response:Response) => {
        response.json();
    });
}
```

The key difference between these two code is that in **Code 2** I placed the brackets after the arrow function to add my tasks inside those brackets and in **Code 1** I took the brackets out and place the task on one line.

My question is why does my object coming from the server side coming back as undefined in **Code2** with the subscribe method that angular2 provided while **Code1** returns the object I suspect.

Comment: With braces you have to use `return` just like  in a classic function.

Comment: Without brackets: expression. With brackets: code block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(response:Response) => response.json()
```

This is *shorthand* for this:

```
(response:Response) => { return response.json(); }
```

The `{}` let you add *multiple* statements inside the block.  Without them, the function just runs the one statement and returns its value.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: You're welcome.  Also, can you clear something up for me?  Why do you have `response:Response` instead of just `response`?  Is that like a type hint or something?

Comment: Uhmm from what the tutorial told me. It is a typescript syntax that ensures me that it is of type Response. So future errors are avoided. Don't take my word for granted though lol I'm still learning. Is it unnecessary?

Comment: It may be necessary in Typescript, I don't know, I've never used it.  In JavaScript, it's a syntax error.