# Arrow function body vs. returning value. ()=>{return value;} vs. ()=>value;

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Is there any difference between returning a value in an arrow function, vs adding the body and typing return?

As far as I'm aware they are the same.

Here's a session:

```
let a = () => 1;
a()
1
let b = () => { return 1; }
b()
1
a
() => 1
b
() => { return 1; }
```

Is there any situation when these are different?

Comment: Yes they are the same.

Comment: with {} you can make body multiline, no other difference

Comment: Related: [Arrow function without curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629962/arrow-function-without-curly-braces), [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions), [ES6 Arrow function with brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730747/es6-arrow-function-with-brackets)

Comment: @juvian you mean multi-statement. Multi-line is always possible even in a single expression.

Comment: @Bergi yeah true

Answer (score 5):

One difference is that returning object literals using the implicit return syntax requires the object literal to be wrapped in parenthesis.

```
var foo = () => { bar: "foobar" }; //This function returns undefined
var foo = () => { return { bar: "foobar" }; }; //This function returns an object
var foo = () => ({ bar: "foobar" }); //This function returns object
```

As far as I'm aware, this is the only difference.

Comment: wonder if this is why i was going through something... during a filter method... this didn't work:    .filter (x => { x == 'a' })   BUT this DID work  .filter(x => x=='a'). Does this have to do with what you said ?

Answer (score 2):

concise body arrow functions implicitly returns value whereas for multi line arrow functions you must explicitly return value.

In your case both will have same net result

Comment: Before you answer, please get your terminology straight. The term "fat arrow" has not been used for several years. Also, it is not a "single line"; it is a "concise body".

Comment: @torazaburo how do you know the term "fat arrow"  has not been used for several years? do you have any metrics? same for "single line"

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative. Please look for references to the term "fat arrow" in the spec, or on MDN. The technical term for the non-`{}` form is perfectly clear: it is "concise body". A concise body could be multiple lines, as in `() => 1 + (NEWLINE) 2`.